# What is the name of photographed hinge?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges

The goal is to order a replacement hinge online (such as Amazon.com) with the correct search words. The hinge is connects the door to the kitchen cabinet:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is called `euro hinge`.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=euro+hinge&iax=images&ia=images

....

Comment: I like that you provided an example in the form of weblink

Comment: Notice that they come a bewildering number of varieties.  Pay attention to how far out it goes, and what the final angle is.  All the more reason to try to compare in person if you can.  Some hardware specialty shops (like Rockler) may have a better selection than say Home Depot.

Comment: Agree with @DaveM - there are a gazillion varieties. I've yet to find a replacement for the ones in either the cheapie flat-pack furniture I've purchased _or_ for IKEA furniture. They all seem to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden kitchen cabinet door hinge, maybe with soft close feature.

Fast amazon search looks like HNBun make, can be mistaken, it was fast look.

Comment: They are readily available in the big box stores and you can see them before you purchase one.